# Android Volley onResponse function not running

Tags: android, django, rest, django-rest-framework, android-volley

Here is my function which I filled in from https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request#java

```
        String url = "http://192.168.1.31:8000/api/social/convert-token";

        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonBody.put("grant_type", "convert_token");
            jsonBody.put("client_id", clientID);
            jsonBody.put("client_secret",clientSecret);
            jsonBody.put("backend", "facebook");
            jsonBody.put("token", facebookAccessToken);
            jsonBody.put("user_type", userType);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //Execute Code
                        Log.d("LOGIN TO SERVER", response.toString());

                        // Save server token to local DB
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                        try {
                            editor.putString("token", response.getString("access_token"));
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        editor.commit();

                        //Start home activity
                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Home.class));

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO: Handle error


                    }
                });
```

The string URL is my Django server, this works properly, I can access it from the web browser on the android phone.

The next block of just converts data I previously got into JSON format. I tested this by copying and pasting the URL, and each parameter in Postman, and it works and returns JSON back.

jsonBody is then passed into the Json Request, along with the URL. The Log.d "LOGIN TO SERVER", is not visible in my log. So I know that the onResponse does not run. Further I put a Log line in the onErrorResponse, and it was visible in my log.

So onReponse does not run, while onError response does. I don't know what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three cases,

1. Check if there are any headers to pass using getHeaders().
   2.As it is http and not https, provide android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in manifest inside . It allows you to access http urls also.
   3.You said you have kept logger in Response.onErrorListener(){}  and what is the error. If not give it by Log.d("Error", "Error getting "+error.toString);

Comment: editing my manifest was it, this was the error displayed by the log too, thank you!

Comment: @G Ganesh Solved!